# Creating files using array items as filenames

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, filenames

I'm trying to create files given an ID and its respective Date. I want to use array items to set the name of these files. Problem is that the outcome is not what i'm expecting when creating the files. I would appreciate your help.

**Desired output:**

I want to create files on the following format:

```
FILE_300002_20170515.txt
FILE_500032_20170426.txt
FILE_400044_20170101.txt
```

**Current output:**

```
FILE_300002_400044.txt
FILE_300002_300002.txt
FILE_300002_500032.txt
```

**File Sample:**

This is the content of my input file:

```
300002,20170515,500032,20170426,400044,20170101
```

**My code:**

```
IFS=',' read -r -a array <<< "$input"   

ini=1
ID=0
Da=1
num="${#array[@]}"
let num=num/2

while [ $ini -le $num ];do
touch "/path/FILE_${array[Da]}_${array[ID]}.txt"
let ini=ini+1
let Da=Da+2
let ID=ID+2
done
```

****I've noticed that using only `'/path/FILE_${array[ID]}.txt'` on the filename, displays all the correct ID's, but when using both,  `'/path/FILE_${array[Da]}_${array[ID]}.txt'` is messed up

Comment: Variable `Da`  vs index `DA`.

Comment: Thanks for the observation Artur, I forgot to change the variable when copying it to the body. Anyhow, the problem persists.

Comment: Could you, please, paste current output after those fix?

Comment: `"/path/FILE_${array[Da]}_${array[ID]}.txt"` may be `/path/FILE_${array[ID]}_${array[Da]}.txt`. The `ID` may be placed first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could do it like this

```
IFS=',' read -r -a array <<< "$input"

for((i=0;i<${#array[@]}-1;i+=2));do

    touch "/path/FILE_${array[i]}_${array[i+1]}.txt"

done
```

Comment: Array indices are already evaluated in an arithmetic context; `${array[i]}` and `${array[i+1]}` are sufficient.

Comment: Same goes for the `for` loop: `for((i=0; i<${#array[@]}-1; i+=2))`.

Comment: @chepner Yeah, don't know why I did that in the loop, but as for array indices, I'm not 100% but pretty sure they don't work like that in older bashes.

Comment: It certainly works that way in 3.2, and the change log implies it's been the way since at least 2.0.

Comment: Thank you for your help "@123" and @chepner. This solution makes what I am expecting. You're awesome!

Comment: @chepner Yep, my bad, tested on my old VM, and it does work, I was thinking of the minus subscript without any leading var/number i.e `${array[-1]}` which I think was added 4+.

Comment: Indeed, I too can never remember when exactly negative subscripts became legal.

Comment: "@123" @chepner What If you have more than one delimiter besides the "comma", a "line break", like this: 
300002,20170515 [A line break]
500032,20170426 [A line break]
400044,20170101 [A line break].

IFS and Read options will change? Like this:
 [ IFS='\n,' read -r -d '' -a array <<< "$input ]

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** alternative approach:

```
awk -F, '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) if($i!="") system("touch FILE_"$i"_"$(i+1)".txt") }' input
```

---

Check result:

```
> ls -1 FILE_*
FILE_300002_20170515.txt
FILE_400044_20170101.txt
FILE_500032_20170426.txt
```

---

- `system(command)` - execute the operating system command *command*

Comment: This solution also meets my expectations, it works! "@Roman" and @123 you really helped me so much. You guys are genius!